# SearchView on recycleview using retrofit

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit2, searchview

i'm building a recycleview list using retrofit, and i want to add searchview on the action bar. but i got error message `No adapter attached; skipping layout`
this is my mainActivity

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ArrayList<AndroidVersion> data;
private DataAdapter adapter;
private SearchView searchView;
private MenuItem searchMenuItem;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.card_recView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    adapter = new DataAdapter(data);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.learn2crack.com/android/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    RequestInterface request = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
    Call<JSONResponse> call = request.getJSON();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponse> call, Response<JSONResponse> response) {
            JSONResponse jsonResponse = response.body();
            data = new ArrayList<AndroidVersion>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getAndroid()));
            adapter.swapData(data);
            Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this, " Hasil", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JSONResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("ERROR", t.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this, " ERROR ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)
            getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    searchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();

    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.
            getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener((SearchView.OnQueryTextListener) this);
    return true;
}
```

}

the code above is just for showing the searchview layout. If anyone have other way or another complete tutorial, please. thanks in advance

**EDIT**
this is my adapter

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder>{

private ArrayList<AndroidVersion> android;
public DataAdapter(ArrayList<AndroidVersion> android){
    this.android = android;
}

@Override
public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_row, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DataAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    viewHolder.nama_dokter.setText(android.get(i).getName());
    viewHolder.alamat_1.setText(android.get(i).getVer());
    viewHolder.alamat_2.setText(android.get(i).getVer());
    viewHolder.alamat_3.setText(android.get(i).getVer());
    viewHolder.total_ps.setText(android.get(i).getApi());
    viewHolder.total_omzet.setText(android.get(i).getApi());
    viewHolder.total_pasien.setText(android.get(i).getApi());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return android.size();
}
private ArrayList<AndroidVersion> data = new ArrayList<>();
public void swapData(ArrayList<AndroidVersion> data) {
    this.data.addAll(data);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private  TextView nama_dokter, alamat_1, alamat_2, alamat_3, total_ps, total_omzet, total_pasien;
    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        nama_dokter = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.nama_dok);
        alamat_1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.alamat_1);
        alamat_2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.alamat_2);
        alamat_3 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.alamat_3);
        total_ps = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.total_ps);
        total_omzet = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.total_omset);
        total_pasien = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.total_pasien);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.card_recView);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new  LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    adapter = new DataAdapter(data);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

inside `onResponse`

`adapter.swapData(data)`

inside `DataAdapter`

```
private ArrayList<AndroidVersion> data= new ArrayList<>();
public void sawpData( ArrayList<AndroidVersion> data) {
            this.data.addAll(data);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Initialize adapter with empty constructor or pass `Context` and inside `onResponse` set `data` like this `adapter.swapData(data)` inside swap data will set you list and call this `notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: i'm sorry, i'm really beginner at this....can you give me more detail, like step by step ? thanks before

Comment: sorry, still error. now the error message is this `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference`
i add my DataAdapter.java in the above

Answer (score 0):

[image: RecyclerView With Search Filter]

I believe you want something related to the gif above.

You can use `notifyDataSetChanged()` to be able to search changed data.